# Does Git ignore directories that are themselves Git repos, by default?

Tags: git

Basically, the question in the subject line, does Git ignore directories that are themselves Git repos, by default?

I am asking because I created a Git repo in a folder that contained a few other repos in subfolders, along then some other files I wanted to track.

I was surprised to find that the new Git repo appeared to automatically ignore the files of those Git repos in the sub-directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a feature of Git. If you initialize a Git repository in a subfolder, then try to add that folder to the parent folder's Git repository, that folder's Git history won't include the subfolder's files.

You can modify those files and try to add them, but you'll get a message like `modified:   some_dir (modified content, untracked content)`. Only the directory name will be tracked.

Submodules were create to address this common scenario. They to allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. If you need to track parent and subfolders, submodules will let you do that.

[This documentation](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) provides a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing a repo that has sub-repos, I would recommend looking at Subtrees as opposed to Submodules for a few reasons:

> There are several reasons why you might find subtree better to use:
>
> - Management of a simple workflow is easy.
> - Older version of git are supported (even before v1.5.2).
> - The sub-project’s code is available right after the clone of the super project is done

See: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

Answer (score -1):

By default Git would assume that your project is a whole and will include all of the folders inside (even if they are separate projects). If you would like to have them treated as separate ones, you can set the one in the subfolder as a submodule:

```
$ cd MainProject
$ git submodule add git@bitbucket.com:me/apps.git apps
$ git commit -a -m "added a submodule"
$ git push
```

You can read more about them at the following URL:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules